# Problems with RabbitMq Managment

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Hello guys I need some help.
I installed rabbitmq managment plugin and it works correctly, but each time when I create "Exclusive queue" it is not displayed in managment plugin, but when I create non-exclusive queue it is shown in plugin. Have you any experiences with this kind of problem?

```
Queue queue = new Queue("queue1",false,true,false,null);
rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
```

Arguments are: queue name,durable flag,exclusive flag,auto-delete flag, arguments

Non-exclusive queue differs in third argument with "false" value and that kind of queue can be displayed in managment. So do you know why exclusive queues cannot be displayed in rabbit managment?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 'exclusive' queue is exclusive to the channel and connection that created it and as such, isn't available to any other consumer, this includes the management plugin.

Its analogue in the database world (if this helps) is a temp table where the table is only available to the current connection and is disposed of afterwards. Such tables are similarly not visible to database management UIs